Alternativa a webapi con blazor web app
Hace unos días me surgió un problema para consumir un webapi en una aplicación Blazor Web App  con estas características:

Cuentas individuales
Elemento de lista
https
Interactive render mode: Auto (server y webassembly)
Interactivity location: Per page/component

Este es el post: Consumir webapi desde cliente con aplicacion Blazor Web APP (auto)
@Yussef me aporto una solución: Programar todos los elementos para aprovechar tanto el rendering del servidor como del cliente, pero a esta solución (que es la más actual) le veo algunos problemas y se planteo la posibilidad de este nuevo post.
Los problemas que yo le veo son los siguientes:

Hay que replicar muchas clases.
Hay que registrar un servicio por cada clase tanto en el cliente como el servidor
Si las clases las has generado desde Entity Framework con DataBase First, cada vez que actualizas el modelo, tienes que revisar todas las clases
No todas las clases tienen métodos en el el interfaz

Hay alguna forma de generar toda esta información y no ir una a una, y sobre todo mantenerla correctamente sin morir en el intento? Por que una clase es aceptable, pero cuando ya usas 15 o 20....
Muchas gracias
